# Where from could I download iPhone system sound files

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to play in my app iPhone system sound files, for example, message sent, message received.

I was expecting to find these sound files available by default in iOS, but it seems not, please, correct me if I'm wrong.

Is there is away to download these default system iPhone sound. I need mainly message sent, message received.

Comment: It depends on the context. Push and Local Notifications do in fact avail system sounds.

Comment: You can use https://github.com/klaas/SwiftySystemSounds to extract the system sounds using the AudioToolbox framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to what WrightCS said, Apple makes it very clear that the only media assets (sounds and pictures) you are allowed to use are the ones that they provide explicitly. If you try to use their sounds they will definitely reject your app.

They also don't want you using their media for anything other than the things they intend them for. Their Human Interface people would have whole litters of kittens if they found out somebody was repurposing their carefully chosen UI elements for other uses, and would reject your app with extreme prejudice.

In short, don't do it. It will get you rejected.

Answer (score 1):

To use sounds in your app, you will either need to create these sounds yourself, or purchase sound effects from a number of different websites. Being that your application is sandboxed, you cannot access the SMS send / receive sounds *(for example)*. I also doubt Apple will allow you to "steal" their sounds for use inside your application. Try searching for free sound effects, [One Example](http://www.grsites.com/archive/sounds/).

Answer (score 0):

Theses resources should help you get started.

https://github.com/TUNER88/iOSSystemSoundsLibrary

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html